# Is there any other parameter in the main method of java other than 'string[] args'?

Tags: java

In java, for a class having

```
public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

Is there any further arguments after `String[] args`

```
public static void main(String[] args | any_arguments_here? ){

}
```

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Well, sure, you can add any parameters you like on a method called `public static void main`; it just then can't be used as an entry point to the program.

Comment: `args` is an array of *unlimited* number of strings, as passed as arguments on the command-line. What *more* do you want?

Comment: You've got a point,but I was asked this in an interview so wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

All the parameters you pass will be receive only in that string array.

In short, No.

Answer (score 0):

What ever you pass in the command it will be held by `args`  array.
e.g if you write `java classname Text1 Text2`, `args[0]` will contain Text1 and `args[1]` will contain Text2

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

This is a trick interview question to trap experienced C/C++ programmers pretending to be Java programmers.

In C/C++ you can declare (and receive from the runtime bootstrap libraries) an 'env' pointer after 'argv', but it is rarely used because it duplicates functionality in the getenv() call.